# Informix oninit-v bad INFORMIXSERVER

Tags: server, configuration, informix

I was able to install Informix in Centos7 without much of troubles. Now that everything is setup im attempting to follow a tutorial to create a DB space. The first step is checking whether the server is up and ready using **oninit -v** command. But this faila with error :

```
bad INFORMIXSERVER
```

yeah, very descriptive...

Can someone help me to troubleshoot this? There is a giant lack of information about Informix on Internet so I dont know where to begin.

Informix version : 12.10

Centos version : 7

Environment variables :

```
-bash-4.2$ echo $INFORMIXDIR
/opt/informix
-bash-4.2$ echo $INFORMIXSERVER
miServidor
-bash-4.2$
```

Regards!

Comment: Appear to missing a `export INFORMIXSERVER` there.

Comment: + your INFORMIXSERVER should match with your `onconfig.$INFORMIXSERVER` filename + the `DBSERVERNAME` inside it + should be listed into the `$INFORMIXSQLHOSTS` , this is the basic to initiate or initialize an instance.

Comment: And if this is a new instance, where you are initializing it for the first time, you are missing the parameter '-i' , but be careful with it!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check if the server is up and running, run "onstat -":

```
informix@irk:/data/informix/IBM/12.10.FC10/tmp$ echo $INFORMIXSERVER
irk1210
informix@irk:/data/informix/IBM/12.10.FC10/tmp$ onstat -

IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC10 -- On-Line -- Up 18 days 02:39:28 -- 219948 Kbytes

informix@irk:/data/informix/IBM/12.10.FC10/tmp$
```

"oninit -v" will attempt to start the server.
"oninit -V" (capital V) will show the version of the oninit binary.

```
informix@irk:/data/informix/IBM/12.10.FC10/tmp$ oninit -V
IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC10 Software Serial Number AAA#B000000
 Mon Oct 23 12:55:56 CDT 2017
informix@irk:/data/informix/IBM/12.10.FC10/tmp$
```

Check that INFORMIXSERVER env variable is set. If not you will get the following errors from 'onstat' and 'oninit':

```
informix@irk:/data/informix/IBM/12.10.FC10/tmp$ unset INFORMIXSERVER

informix@irk:/data/informix/IBM/12.10.FC10/tmp$ oninit -v
bad INFORMIXSERVERinformix@irk:/data/informix/IBM/12.10.FC10/tmp$ 

informix@irk:/data/informix/IBM/12.10.FC10/tmp$ onstat -
shared memory not initialized for INFORMIXSERVER '<NULL>'

informix@irk:/data/informix/IBM/12.10.FC10/tmp$
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did so and now Im getting this : 
shared memory not initialized for INFORMIXSERVER 'miServidor'. what does this mean ? @J_S

Comment: That's means your server is not initialized. Basically, you need to initialize the instance which will create all the "stuff" in your chunks. If you start the informix server  with "oninit -iv" it should dump a lot of messages in the console, and hopefully, at the end you should have an instance running.  

"oninit -i" has to be used only once, after all the disk structures are created, you should shutdown the instance with "onmode -kuy" and start it with just "oninit", otherwise you may loose all your databases.

Comment: correction ;)  "shared memory not initialized" means the Informix server is not up and running, if is the first time you start the instance, you need to use the "-i" as mentioned above, for any other time, just start the informix server with "oninit". No "-i" otherwise bad things will happen ;)

Comment: Thanks so much! Now I got it up and running and I could create my first dbspace, database and table. :)